# Suggest an alternative to be used in place of "However"

Tags: word-choice, alternatives

The last line of the following paragraph sounds fishy. Could you suggest another transition word for the word **however**?

> I learned many things over the course of my three month internship at
>   a startup, Crunch. I worked with a team to build a recommendation
>   system and handle interfacing between client-side and the backend
>   server. **However**, there was one thing I had ascertained. My chosen
>   major was, indeed, Computer Science.

Comment: _However_ isn't fishy here, it's superfluous, because there is nothing in the previous sentence to which it refers. In order for _however_ to make sense, the first sentence would have to state that there was something the speaker had _not_ ascertained.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Could you suggest another word to be used as a transition word?

Comment: I'm confused about whether the author leaned many things or one thing.

Comment: I think **ascertain** is slightly off here.  **to ascertain** means to confirm  something by experimentation or directed investigation, not "to discover through lived experience".  We can ascertain whether a water sample contains lead, or we can ascertain how much money is in a bank account. It would be an odd use to say, "I had never tried snowboarding until that day, when I ascertained that my career dream was to become a professional snowboarder."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *In the process*, there was one thing I had ascertained.

or

> *During my internship*, there was one thing I had ascertained.

Answer (score 3):

*However* is normally used to express contrast. In your example we don't see what it refers to. Thus you **shouldn't** use any of its synonyms like *but*. I suggest you use *and* instead.You need a discourse marker to provide some *additional* information.

Answer (score 2):

Like @P.E Dant said, **However** is superfluous.

> An old-fashioned rule was that you shouldn’t start a sentence with however, but today however is often used at the beginning of a sentence to mean ‘but’, ‘nevertheless’ or ‘regardless of the fact’.

[Link](http://www.onlinegrammar.com.au/however-commas-or-semicolons/)

I suggest you to use **[anyway](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/anyway)** or **but**.

> I learned many things over the course of my three month internship at a startup, Crunch. I worked with a team to build a recommendation system and handle interfacing between client-side and the back end server. Anyway, there was one thing I had ascertained. My chosen major was, indeed, Computer Science.

## Other Resources

You can check others synonyms and resources googling "Use however" and "Synonyms however", I can't post it because I haven't 10+ reputation.